# Using <FragmentContainerView> instaed of <fragment> causes the app to crash on using BottomNav and jetpack navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

I am creating an app with a BottomNavigationView.

I am using JetpackNavigation and kotlin.

I have set up my XML as

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragNavHost"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavView"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_nav_graph"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu">
```

***But I'm getting a `Replace the <fragment> tag with FragmentContainerView.` suggestion message from the Android Studio suggestions***

The app breaks when using FragmentContainerView  but runs perfectly on using fragment

The error I'm getting is

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.reportbusterclone/com.example.reportbusterclone.view.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.reportbusterclone.view.MainActivity@f462d5a does not have a NavController set on 2131296446
```

even though only the tag changes and nothing else.